# Timer Does Not Fire Before Application Ends in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have simple Console application in C# that creates a timer to write text to the Console. Then it waits for the user to press a key.

If the user presses a key before five seconds elapse, then the application ends, and the timer never fires. If the user does not press a key, then the timer fires as expected.

Why does the thread that the timer creates not keep the application from terminating? How should I ensure that the application keeps running even if the user presses a key?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        timer.Interval = 5000; // 5 seconds
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Timer Fired.");
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the timer message to always write out, you can have the main thread wait on a [reset event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) that is signaled once the timer is fired.

```
    static ManualResetEvent timerFired = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        timer.Interval = 5000; // 5 seconds
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();

        // This call will return only after timerFired.Set() is
        // called.  So, if the user hits a key before the timer is
        // fired, this will block for a little bit, until the timer fires.  
        // Otherwise, it will return immediately
        timerFired.WaitOne();
    }

    public static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Timer Fired.");
        timerFired.Set();
    }
```

As for the other question, why doesn't it prevent the application from exiting, I'll take a stab.  The `timer_Elapsed()` is being called from a background thread.  According to MSDN, background threads don't keep the execution environment running.  There's a [nice discussion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0(v=vs.110).aspx) here.

ThreadPool threads are background threads, and MSDN Timer documentation indicates that the Timer's [Elapsed event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx) is raised on a ThreadPool thread, so the application wouldn't wait for it as it's not a foreground thread.

Comment: Great answer, only ThreadPool threads are not background threads, any CLR-managed thread (i.e. an instance of `System.Threading.Thread`) can be marked as background or foreground, regardless of whether its instance is pooled or not.

Comment: @BorisB. Thanks for the comment.  Let's try to clarify the answer.  While we can change the ThreadPool thread from background to foreground, is it safe to consider them background threads by default, or is that indeterminate?